# Login with hashed password in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have store password with hashing in codeigniter. After that, I want to Login with hashed password. Secondly, i have to pass the user's id.. i have take help of this website but it lands on error page.
i have used `password_verify()`. but it gives long error

**what i have tried**
**model**

```
 public function isvalidateuser($email,$password)
    {
        $q = $this->db->where(['email'=>$email,'password'=>$password])
                    ->get('user');
                    $row = $q->row();

                    if(password_verify($password,$row->password))
                    {
                       
                        return $q->row()->id;
                      
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
    }
```

**controller**

```
public function  userloginvalidation1()
{
    $email    = $this->input->post('email');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');

    $this->load->model('loginmodel');
    
    $id = $this->loginmodel->isvalidateuser($email, $password);
    
    if ($id) {
   
        // You probably want to do this in model ↓↓
        $userName = $this->db->select('name')->from('user')->where('id', $id)->get()->row(); // get the name from the table

        $this->load->library('session'); // autoloading the session library is a good idea
        
        // set the session 
        $this->session->set_userdata('id', $id);
        $this->session->set_userdata('name', $userName->name); // or simply $_SESSION['name'] = $userName->name;
        
        return redirect('user/userdashboard');
    
    } else {
        
        echo "not login;";
        exit();
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->session->set_flashdata('loginfailed', 'invalid username or password');
     
        return redirect('user/userlogin');
    }      
}
```

**the error ihave got**

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property 'password' of non-object

Filename: models/loginmodel.php

Line Number: 16

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\application\models\loginmodel.php
Line: 16
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\application\controllers\user.php
Line: 45
Function: isvalidateuser

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

not login;
```

how to solve this error???? help!!!

Comment: Sounds like your query failed and my guess it because of `'password'=>$password`. The password won't match it is not hashed.

Comment: @user3783243: any solution for this!!! it will be much helpful!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with code in model

```
$q = $this->db->where(['email'=>$email,'password'=>$password])
                    ->get('user');
                    $row = $q->row();
```

You are querying the database table on field email and password. I assume **password** field store hash value and you are querying with raw value. The query will never return any data.

So you should do as follow

```
$q = $this->db->where(['email'=>$email)
                    ->get('user');
                    $row = $q->row();
```

Now you should have hashed password from table to compare.

Still you code have an issue and will throw same error when it can't find any data where email is missing. To avoid that you can

```
if($q->num_rows()>0){
   // your Code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[**mail2bapi**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62801923/1592845) is fine answer. However, `$row` must be checked for `non null` value before proceeding in the verification, suppose someone supply the login with non registered email!

So it would be like:

```
public function isvalidateuser($email,$password)
    {
        $q = $this->db->where(['email'=>$email])
                    ->get('user');
                    $row = $q->row();
                    if (!is_null($row)){

                      if(password_verify($password,$row->password))
                      {
                       
                          return $q->row()->id;
                      
                      }

                      else
                      {
                          return false;
                      }
                   }
                    else{
                        return false;
                   } 
    }
```